# Cost of running small kubernetes cronjob?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-cronjob

I am currently learning kubernetes and would like to run a cronjob every 6 hours (job is running under a minute). Minikube is not suitable as I cannot ensure my laptop stay alive 24h/7d... I wonder what is the cost on main kubernetes providers (GCP, AWS, Azure) for this type of workload? Is it better to rent a VM and install a small kubernetes instance to do so?

Thanks

Getting former user feedback will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look to [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) and [Cloud Run jobs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs) that allow you to run container in serverless mode.

In addition, you can also have a look to [GKE Autopilot](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview) where you pay only when you consume resource on the cluster (and the first cluster is free).

Comment: thanks, I will have a look at these services.